# Como executar uma função cujo nome foi passado como parâmetro de outra função, à la callback?

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

Criei esta função com o objetivo de abstrair as chamadas `$.ajax()` para serem executadas em vários momentos diferentes. Um dos parâmetros dela é o nome de uma das funções que eu gostaria que fosse executada em caso de sucesso.

Entretanto, como devo fazer a chamada à esta "callback"?

```
function submitData(myCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        success: function(res){
            myCallback(res);
        }
    });

}

function processarResponse(response) {

}
```

---

Finalizando com a ajuda recebida de Valdeir Psr: a passagem do parâmetro 'myCallback' deve ser feita passando-se o nome e a assinatura da callback:

```
submitData(processarResponse(response));
```

Comment: Obrigado pela edição; gostei de sua concisão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta utilizar `nome_da_funcao()`, por exemplo:

```js
function exec( fun ) {
  fun("World") //Passando parâmetros
}

exec( function() {
  console.log("Success")
} )

exec( function(res) {
  console.log(`Hello ${res}`)
} )
```

Baseado em seu exemplo:

```js
function submitData(myCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
        success: function(res){
            myCallback(res);
        }
    });
}

submitData(function(res) {
  console.log( "Título do POST: ", res.title )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Você ainda você utilize o [**apply**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply) ou o [**call**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call), por exemplo:

```
myCallback.call(null, res)
myCallback.apply(null, [res])
```

Exemplo:

```js
function submitData(myCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
        success: function(res){
            myCallback.call(null, res)
        }
    });
}

submitData(function(res) {
  console.log( "Título do POST: ", res.title )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Por favor, você poderia mostrar como eu faria isso no exemplo da pergunta inicial? É meio embaraçoso, mas não consegui aplicar seu conceito na prática de exemplo dado.

Comment: @jCintra Atualizei o exemplo

Answer (score 1):

Apenas remova as aspas que vai funcionar:

```
function submitData(myCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        success: function(res){
            myCallback(res);
        }
    });
}
```

myCallback deve estar apto a receber o parâmetro passado